# Password protected shell script

Tags: shell

I want to make my script password protected. If I use this code it works:

```
ACTUAL="sam123"
read -s -p "Password: " enteredpass
```

I also want to protect the script from being read with `cat` and `vi`. I tried to use `vim -x <script>` to encrypt it but then it won't allow me to run it.

I am using a generic user and haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: You can't do this in a way that will actually stick (can't be trivially circumvented) without help from your sysadmin.

Comment: ...basically, you need to have the script run as a completely different user from the shared account, and set up a mechanism (be it a C wrapper with the `setuid` bit set, or an appropriate `/etc/sudoers` configuration) allowing that script to be invoked from the shared account; only when it's on the other side of a privilege boundary is it secure against someone reading its text, tracing its execution, etc.

Comment: ...well, you *could* just have a wrapper for the script that's plaintext, and the content actually be encrypted. That'll work up to a point, the point being when another user in the shared account runs `strace -p yourpid -f` to trace what your shell does when you invoke the script and enter the password to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't do this *securely* without your sysadmin's help, but you can do something sorta-kinda-maybe-not-really-adequate without it.

So, let's say you create your script like so:

```
cat >myscript <<EOF
echo "Doing something super secret here"
EOF
```

...but you don't want anyone who doesn't know the password to run it, even if they're using a shared account. You can do this by encrypting it:

```
gpg -ac <myscript >myscript.asc
```

...and then embedding that plaintext into a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{ gpg -d | bash -s "$@"; } <<'EOF'
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

jA0EBwMCBogTuO9LcuZg0lsB2wqrsPU8Bw2DRzAZr+hiecYTOe//ajXfcjPI4G6c
P3anEYb0N4ng6gsOhKqOYpZU9JzVVkxeL73CD1GSpcQS46YlKWJI8FKcPckR6BE+
7vqkcPWwcS7oy4H2
=gmFu
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
EOF
```

---

That said, other users in the shared account can still collect your password if they connect to and trace your process while it's running -- running `strace` on the copy of `bash -s` will show the text being fed into its stdin. **In general, you shouldn't rely on shared accounts for anything that needs to remain confidential.**

Answer (score 1):

Late answer for posterity, how about using openssl? here's my scriptencrypt.sh

It generates a new .sh file that requires a password

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo "usage: $(basename $0) script"; exit 1; fi

script=$(cat "$1")
checksum="$(echo "$script" | md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }')"
extension=$([[ "$(basename $1)" =~ .\.. ]] && echo ".${1##*.}" || echo "")

cat << EOF > "${1%.*}.enc${extension}"
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' encrypted_script << EOF2
$(openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in /dev/stdin -out /dev/stdout <<< "${script}")
EOF2

read -s -p "Enter script password: " password
echo
unencrypted_script=\$(openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt -in /dev/stdin -out /dev/stdout <<< "\${encrypted_script}" -pass pass:"\${password}" 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\000')
clear
checksum="\$(echo "\$unencrypted_script" | md5sum | awk '{ print \$1 }')"
if [ "\${checksum}" = "${checksum}" ]; then
    eval "\${unencrypted_script}"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Wrong password inserted"
    exit 1
fi
EOF
```

Comment: Hmm. The `<<<"${script}"` is the only place you're doing an unquoted expansion in your outer heredoc, right? Considered changing from `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'` and passing that through the environment instead of expanding its text?

Comment: I would also strongly suggest switching from `==` to `=` inside `[` for the sake of encouraging [standards-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) usage by default. Sure, the shebang is bash, but folks who see `==` used inside `[` or do so themselves are more likely to continue to follow the practice in code that needs to be compatible with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's not, the whole `$(openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in /dev/stdin -out /dev/stdout <<< "${script}")` expansion is done in the outer script for the first heredoc; there's also the second `${checksum}` expansion. I'll change the `==` though

Comment: @CharlesDuffy BTW did you mean changing `EOF2` to `'EOF2'`?

Comment: No, I meant `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'`. Clearly you *do* want the command substitution inside the EOF2 heredoc to be run.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha re: `checksum`. I'd probably export the outer one through the environment with a different name; that way you don't need to use string substitution to generate code, with all the hairiness that implies.

Comment: BTW, the caveats I gave on my answer (about how this shouldn't be done for anything where security is genuinely important) still apply here. Lots of ways to change a bash script's behavior to run arbitrary code (or just enable shell options like `xtrace`) through the environment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll admit it's a bit convoluted, but it's actually the opposite, the command substitution inside the `EOF2` heredoc is actually ran inside the first `EOF` heredoc, as well as the second `${checksum}` substitution, so while changing `EOF2` to `'EOF2'` won't change anything, changing `EOF` to `'EOF'` will break the script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209336/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-alex-sim).